# Alterar aba do TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando um fomulário WindowsForm e estou usando um TabControl e gostaria de criar um evento que alterasse a aba que está sendo exibida.

Consegui fazer alterar o conteúdo exibido com `this.tabForm.TabPages["nomeTab"].Show();` ou `tabPage1.Show();`, as duas opções deram certo, mas apenas o conteúdo que está sendo exibido é alterado, a aba selecionada permanece a mesma.

Como resolvo esse problema?

Comment: geralmente eu altero o selectedindex do tabcontrol, ex: tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;

Comment: Fiz dessa forma e deu certo. Obrigado Lucas.

Comment: boa noite, Vinícius, responda sua pergunta e marque como certa para organizar a comunidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas de alterar o separador/tabulador selecionado num `TabControl`.

**`SelectedIndex`**

```
tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

**`SelectedTab`**

```
// aqui a atribuição é feita pelo objeto do separador/tabulador
tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage;
```

**`SelectTab()`**

```
// aqui é evocado um método para selecionar o separador/tabulador
// tem 3 overloads: 
//      index (int)           = por índice
tabControl.SelectTab(0);
//      tabPageName (string)  = por nome
tabControl.SelectTab("tabPage");
//      tabPage (TabPage)     = por objeto
tabControl.SelectTab(tabPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui alterar usando o selectedindex do tabcontrol, ex: `tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;`